# prefilling SESSION[SESS_PREFIX

Tags: php, session

On my home page there is a link to another page.. when I go from my homepage to let say the order page..  the order page is working..

But when I go to my order page directly.. I got an error:

### **Notice: Undefined index: banner_type  on line 33**

// line 33

### $_SESSION[SESS_PREFIX .'type'] = $_POST['banner_type'];

the prefill must be kozijnen.. what code can i use for the order page to work. when I visit it directly?

```
if ( isset ( $_SESSION[SESS_PREFIX .'type'] ) ) {



    // check flyer

    if ( $_SESSION[SESS_PREFIX .'type'] == "kozijnen" ) {
```

I need to hard code the kozijnen into my order page..

**this is a part off the code from my home page:**

$value ) {

                                    // output
                                    //echo '';

                                }

                                ?>

                                
                                
                                    Postcode
                                    
                                
                                
                                    Straal
                                    
                                        10 km
                                        25 km
                                        50 km
                                        100 km
                                        Overal
                                    
                                
                                
                                    Werkzaamheden
                                    
                                        $value ) {
                                            echo ''. $value .'';
                                        }
                                        ?>
                                    
                                
                                --->

**and this from my order page..**

/ chek sessions step1

if ( !isset($_SESSION[SESS_PREFIX .'postal']) OR !isset($_SESSION[SESS_PREFIX .'radius']) OR !isset($_SESSION[SESS_PREFIX .'type']) ) {

```
// fill in

$_SESSION[SESS_PREFIX .'type'] = $_POST['banner_type'];




// check isset submit

if ( isset ( $_POST['banner_search_submit'] ) ) {

    header("Location: ". $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);

}
```

}

// check step 2

if ( isset ( $_POST['gotostep2'] ) OR isset ( $_POST['adjuststep1'] ) ) {

```
$_SESSION[SESS_PREFIX .'type'] = $_POST['type'];
```

}

--
/ check type isset

//echo ( isset ( $$_SESSION[SESS_PREFIX .'type'] = "kozijnen" ) {

if ( isset ( $_SESSION[SESS_PREFIX .'type'] ) ) {

```
// check flyer

if ( $_SESSION[SESS_PREFIX .'type'] == "kozijnen" ) {
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question.

Comment: If your homepage is setting session variables needed to the order page to work, it's probably the correct flow and you should not mess with it. If that's unavoidable, you should present more explanations on your expectations and more of your code.

Comment: In that case, going from one place to another creates an array index (inside some array we can't know for sure because you didn't specified it) called "banner_type", that when you access it directly, cannot be set.

Comment: I still don't get your question, but perhaps this is what you need: `$_SESSION[SESS_PREFIX .'type'] = isset($_SESSION[SESS_PREFIX .'type']) ? $_SESSION[SESS_PREFIX .'type'] : 'kozijnen';`

Comment: Yes Epodax! it working! thank you! it was difficult to explain sorry for that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Deducted from the comments, what you were looking for is called a [ternary operator](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php#language.operators.comparison.ternary)

It can be used in a different set of ways but in general it's used to assign a "default" value if no value is present.

And one of the way it works are like so:

```
$value = (CHECK) ? <VALUE IF CHECK PASSES> : <VALUE IF CHECK FAILS>;
```

As stated in comments you should / could use it like so:

```
$_SESSION[SESS_PREFIX .'type'] = isset($_SESSION[SESS_PREFIX .'type']) ? $_SESSION[SESS_PREFIX .'type'] : 'kozijnen';
```